# Задача из E-Olymp:Функция-3

Tags: c, математика

[Ссылка к задаче](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/8241).
Впринципе программу для этой задачи написал ,но есть условие ,что нужно для каждого теста вывести в отдельной строке значение функции.А у меня только 1 тест и 1 значение=программа не принимается.Как правильно написать,чтобы все по условию было верно?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
double f(double x,double y){
return x*x +sin(x*y)-y*y;
}
int main()
{
double x,y;
scanf("%lf %lf",&x,&y);
f(x,y);
printf("%.4lf",f(x,y));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: А к чему такая реакция на задачу?Почему плохие оценки ставите?

Comment: Условия перечитайте: **Каждая строка** содержит два действительных числа **x** и **y**., а вы читаете одну строку.

Comment: @こきん Ну это и есть мой вопрос ,я читаю одну строку,а как написать так,чтоб было по условию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дабы для каждого теста вывести в отдельной строке значение функции нужно не просто написать scanf,а использовать конструкцию while(scanf...),т.е пока вводятся значения, выводить на экран значение функции

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h>  
double f(double x,double y)  {  
return x*x +sin(x*y)-y*y;  
}  
int main()  
{  
double x,y;  
while(scanf("%lf %lf",&x,&y)==2)  {  
 f(x,y);  
printf("%.4lf\n",f(x,y));  
}  
return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте к своему ответу дополнительную информацию. В текущем виде ваше решение сложно понять.